# Rehydrating state from both local storage and URL hash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, redux, local-storage

I've written the following reducer and it works, but it feels that I'm stepping into mutation land and that there probably is a better way to achieve this. I have an object in the state called reading. A reading can be extracted from a hash in a URL, as well as from a record of readings called oldReadings stored inside the reading object. A third way is to extract it from persisted state in local storage. I want the URL extracting to be prioritised to make sharing easy. Is this approach OK, and if not, could you point me in the right direction?

```
import { GENERATE_READING, GET_READING_FROM_HASH } from '../constants/actionTypes';
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants';
import getHashFromUrl from '../utils/getHashFromUrl';
import getReadingFromHash from '../utils/getReadingFromHash';

// Check if URL has hash and set initial state to that reading.
const initialUrlHash = getHashFromUrl(window.location.pathname);
const initialUrlReading = initialUrlHash ? getReadingFromHash(initialUrlHash) : null;
const initialState = {
  arr: initialUrlReading ? initialUrlReading.arr : [],
  hash: initialUrlHash ? initialUrlHash : '',
  time: 0,
  oldReadings: []
};

export const reading = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GENERATE_READING: {
      let reading = action.reading;
      // If old readings exists, save new reading to array of old readings.
      if (state.oldReadings) {
        reading.oldReadings = [ {
          hash: reading.hash,
          time: reading.time,
          amount: reading.arr.length
        }, ...state.oldReadings ];
        reading.oldReadings = reading.oldReadings.slice(0, 5);
      }
      // Otherwise create new array and save reading to it.
      else {
        reading.oldReadings = [{
          hash: reading.hash,
          time: reading.time,
          amount: reading.arr.length
        }];
      }

      return { ...state, ...reading };
    }

    case GET_READING_FROM_HASH:
      // Used when restoring reading for old hash.
      return { ...state, ...action.reading };

    case REHYDRATE: {
      const incoming = action.payload.reading;
      // If hydrating from local storage, check for hash in url and append
      // that reading on top of reading from local storage.
      if (incoming) {
        const urlHash = getHashFromUrl(window.location.pathname);
        if (urlHash && incoming.hash !== urlHash) {
          const urlReading = getReadingFromHash(urlHash);
          return { ...state, ...incoming, ...urlReading };
        } else {
          return { ...state, ...incoming };
        }
      } else {
      return state;
      }
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reading;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could make use of `Object.assign` to avoid mutations and streamline your code.  For example rather than `let reading = action.reading` which is still just a reference to the original object you could do `const reading = Object.assign({}, action.reading)`.  This essentially takes a new empty object and copies `action.reading`into it.  Take a look at the docs, `Object.assign` is invaluable for this type of thing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Good point! I'll make sure to fix that. My main point of worry is the "un-pureness" of relying on `window.location` and not only the state/action, however.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense.  You could dispatch an action from your application wrapper's `componentDidMount` with the `window.location.pathname` as the payload, that way you know that window is available.  It might make things a little cleaner.

Comment: That sounds like a really good idea, will definitely look into this! Hopefully that dispatches before the rehydration action, and if so I could just add something like a `hasSyncedFromUrl` flag to check in the `REHYDRATE` case.